# Strange Margin in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIViewController with a few UIViews (built using Interface Builder) including one that I want to use as a WKWebView. I have been able to create the WKWebView and load it as a subview to one of these UIViews --  but when I load the URL I get this strange padding on the top and left. I had the same issue when I use the UIWebView but was able to solve it using

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

However this does not seem to help at all with the WKWebView that has been loaded dynamically.

I also get the same padding when loading a page from the web so I know its not in my local html.

Edit: I am beginning to wonder whether autolayout in the container UIView is causing this...

Here is the relevant code:

```
    var webView:WKWebView!
@IBOutlet var containerView : UIView?
@IBOutlet weak var webContainer: UIView!

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.webView = WKWebView()
    if(self.webView != nil){
        self.containerView = self.webView!
        self.containerView!.frame = self.webContainer.frame
        self.webContainer.addSubview(self.containerView!)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let url = bundle.URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Here is what it looks like. The BG color of the UIView container is dark grey -- and you'll also note that the html seems to extend beyond the UIView even though I set the frame of the WebView to be the same as the UIView container:

[image]

Comment: I was loading the html source myself in the webview. Adding the style tag and setting the margin to zero worked for me. <style> body{margin:0;} </style>

Answer (score 15):

This is because `WKWebView` preserves space for the navigation bar by using an appropriate `contentInset`. However, since your WKWebView is a subview, this adjustment is not necessary anymore.

```
self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

It is important to do this after the `viewDidLoad` method. For example in `didFinishedNavigation` in the `WKNavigationDelegate`

Comment: Fun fact, in Swift this is even lovelier to write: `webView.scrollView.contentInset = .zero`

Comment: The Objective-C equivalent would be: `webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero`

Answer (score 10):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
  if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, your answer might be correct, but try to add some explanation to your code :)

Comment: Wrong language.

Comment: In Swift 5, the following was sufficient:
`webView.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Comment: This answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Should be used WKNavigationDelegate

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
NSString *cssString = @"body { padding:0; margin:0}";
NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style);", cssString];
[webView evaluateJavaScript:jsString completionHandler:nil];}
```